# Skip tests on checkout during maven release:perform

Tags: maven

During the maven release:perform goal, the prepared tag is being checked out from SCM and a build seems to be attempted in a forked maven instance.

I'd like the tests to be skipped at that point, because for whatever reason, they fail (the build involves running a test web-application via cargo, and I believe this just doesn't work well in this environment).

Is there any way to instruct maven to do this?

Comment: I am not sure if this what you are looking for `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Comment: I'm referring to the behavior described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html_ "release:perform will fork a new Maven instance to build the checked-out project. This new Maven instance will use the same system configuration and Maven profiles used by the one running the release:perform goal." - I'd like to tell this particular maven instance to skip the tests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify arguments to the forked maven instance on the command line:

```
mvn release:prepare -Darguments="-DskipTests"
mvn release:perform -Darguments="-DskipTests"
```

or specify a maven-release-plugin configuration in your pom, perhaps under pluginManagement:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <arguments>-DskipTests</arguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Could you please help me ? I am doing the build on Jenkins. I am using -Dresume=false -Darguments="-DskipTests" release:prepare release:perform .