# [Jenkins]: Override value of maven -f option

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, release

How to override the value for  '-f' option in Jenkins maven releae build?

i tried with -Df "mymodule/pom.xml" but it is does not get reflected in jenkins.

The maven uses below command when a release is triggered.

```
 Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\Jenkins\workspace\myproject_ci\pom.xml
 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2-SNAPSHOT 
-DreleaseVersion=1.1 
-Dusername=XXXXX -Dpassword=********* 
-Dtag=myproject-tag-1.1 
-Df mymodule/pom.xml 
-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform
```

Now i have to override the value for -f option that jenkins uses for release.

Any ideas?

Comment: As Maven forks the process to launch the release build, maybe you have to use the -Darguments option (like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496039/skip-tests-on-checkout-during-maven-releaseperform)

Answer (score 0):

use param in Jenkins :
Root POM = mymodule/pom.xml